# the ball move to position action_down in android

Tags: android, canvas

I have a ball in the screen .I want When I implemented action_down , the ball will move to this position .This my code :

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            x1 = (int) event.getX();
            y1 = (int) event.getY();

            float dx = x1-x;
            float dy = y1-y;
            float d = (float)Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
            vx = dx*4/d;
            vy = dy*4/d;
        }
}
```

and onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix2.postTranslate(x - bitmap.getWidth()/2, y - bitmap.getHeight()/2);
        x = x+vx ;
        y = y+vy ;

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
}
```

When ,the ball will move to position action_down .But Why the ball was in the position action_down ,it don't stop ?

Please help me?
Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of vx, vy to int

```
    vx = (int)dx*4/d;
    vy = (int)dy*4/d;
```

And then use this

```
    if(Math.abs(x - x1) <= Math.abs(vx) 
        && Math.abs(y - y1) <= Math.abs(vy)){ 
            vx = 0; 
            vy = 0; 
            x = x1;
            y = y1;
    }
```

Comment: When the ball was in the position action_down I add :

Comment: When the ball was in the position action_down I do:

if(x == x1 && y == y1){

vx = 0; vy = 0; } But Why it don't stop ?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your question. What's the type of x, y, vx, vy? int or float? The x and y may not equal to x1 and y1 if the type of vx and vy is float. Maybe if(x >= x1 && y >= y1){ vx = 0; vy = 0; } will work.

Comment: if(x >= x1 && y >= y1){ vx = 0; vy = 0; } the ball will not move free in screen .if I want (x == x1 && y == y1) ,How to I can set the conditions for x, y ?